# Symmetric polynomials and the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials that all (now we consider the homogenous case) symmetric polynomials can be written up as the polynomial of symmetric polynomials.

But does the number of steps in the reduction (i.e. the number of factors) have a (non-trvial) upper bound (as do the number of steps in the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency))?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask about the number of steps of the theorem; you need to present a specific reduction algorithm and ask about its number of steps.

Comment: @Greg Sorry, I mean the algorithm in the best known proofs of the theorem. And since the decomposition is unique the number of factors is always the same.

Comment: @TamielFarken: what is the trivial upper bound?